# Specify additional files to clean when doing a "make clean" with autoconf

Tags: autoconf

I am using autoconf. Right now I have an intermediate .cpp file that is generated. I want to have the .cpp file deleted when I do a "make clean".

I tried specifying the file in a `CONFIG_CLEAN_FILES` variable, but that only takes effect when I do a `make distlclean`. Is there a variable to set to delete the file when I do a `make clean`? If not, how do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct MOSTLYCLEANFILES or CLEANFILES. DISTCLEANFILES is for "make distclean"

Thanks @Rhys for the correct link to http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Clean.html#Clean

Answer (score 1):

Use DISTCLEANFILES, I think.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Clean.html#Clean

Comment: Actually, it looks like I want to use MOSTLYCLEANFILES or CLEANFILES